# Why does this code keep appearing in my code even if I delete it and save it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This specific line of code keeps reappearing in this file `const { clean } = require("underscore");`, it is very top of this file. I even delete it and save it, and it will come back later on. It is fine in other files that are linked to this file. The only thing I have related to this line is one file called clean.js which is just function that removes my text and buttons and stuff.

```
function clear() {

  $('.texts').remove();

  $('.buttons').remove();

  $('.lines').remove();

  $('.brs').remove();

  $('.e-buttons').remove();

  $('.centers').remove();

};
```

Any idea why this appearing? Maybe it has something to do with the Jquery database?

```
const { clean } = require("underscore");

var Dif = '';

function download(filename, text) {
    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
    pom.click();
};

function Systems(core) {

    if (core == 'Main_Menu') {

        clear();

        $("<p class='texts' >This is a main menu, please pick New Game, Save Game, Load Game, or Options.</p>").insertBefore("#placeholder");

    }

    else if (core == 'Save') {

        download ('Files/Address.txt', 'You are ' + gender + ', by the name of ' + pn + ', and you claim to be a ' + OBG + '.');
        //add a way for player to change Files/Address.txt into what they want by use input, then attach that to variable and then use that variable to replace the name of file in download format above this comment.
    
        console.log("save complete successful!");
    
    }

    else if (core == 'Option') {

        clear();

        $('<center class=\'centers\'><button class=\'command_button d-buttons\' value=\'difficulty\'>Difficulty</button></center><br class=\'brs\'>').insertBefore('#placeholder_choice');

    }

};

$(document).on('click', '.d-buttons', function() {

    var button = $(this).val();
    console.log('The Button is ' + button);
    $('#console').scrollTop($('#console')[0].scrollHeight);

    if (button == 'difficulty') {

        clear();

        $('<center class=\'centers\'><button class=\'command_button d-buttons\' value=\'easy\'>Easy</button></center><br class=\'brs\'>').insertBefore('#placeholder_choice');

        $('<center class=\'centers\'><button class=\'command_button d-buttons\' value=\'normal\'>Normal</button></center><br class=\'brs\'>').insertBefore('#placeholder_choice');

        $('<center class=\'centers\'><button class=\'command_button d-buttons\' value=\'hard\'>Hard</button></center><br class=\'brs\'>').insertBefore('#placeholder_choice');

    }

    else if (button == 'easy') {

        clean();
        point = 800;
        Dif = 'easy';
        console.log("The difficulty is on " + Dif + ". You have " + point + " of points now.");
        $('<p class=\'texts\'>You are now playing on easy mode.</p>').insertBefore('#placeholder');

    }

    else if (button == 'normal') {

        clean();
        point = 400;
        Dif = 'normal';
        console.log("The difficulty is on " + Dif + ". You have " + point + " of points now.");
        $('<p class=\'texts\'>You are now playing on normal mode.</p>').insertBefore('#placeholder');

    }

    else if (button == 'hard') {

        clean();
        point = 200;
        Dif = 'hard';
        console.log("The difficulty is on " + Dif + ". You have " + point + " of points now.");
        $('<p class=\'texts\'>You are now playing on hard mode.</p>').insertBefore('#placeholder');

    }

});

// $('<p class=\'texts\'></p>').insertBefore('#placeholder');

// $('<center class=\'centers\'><button class=\'command_button buttons\' value=\' \'></button></center><br class=\'brs\'>').insertBefore('#placeholder_choice');

// $('<input type=\'text\' class=\'command_line lines\' size=\'50\' autofocus=\'autofocus\' autocomplete=\'off\'></input>').insertBefore('#placeholder').fadeIn(0);

//$('<button class=\'command_button e-buttons\' value=\'pistol\'>Pistol</button>').insertBefore('#placeholder_choice');
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: "the Jquery database" huh??

Comment: I mean the Jquery database as in where the whole Jquery code is from. I believe it called a library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `clear` function you declared invoked in some places, and `clean` in others.

Depending on what IDE/editor you're using and how you've configured it, if you don't actually have the `clean` function declared anywhere, I have a feeling it's auto importing the first `clean` function it can find in your directory.

Comment: I check and notice no clean reference, only clear. But I did notice that name of the file is clean rather than clear.js. So I went and change it to clear.js. But to be safe so it does not come back, I just comment that line out, this way it should not auto importing that line in...

Comment: In the button == "easy"/"normal"/"hard" cases, you use a clean function. is that intentional?

Comment: Huh, that is odd, I did not notice that there is clean(); in this post, as my shown clear(); Did I somehow change while working on this project? But yet, it seems that this post is a bit outdated as I work on it yesterday. but yes, it is no longer clean(); but clear();.

I will remove that comment with first line and just deleted whole line. if it somehow come back, then there is still something left. otherwise I will mark you as correct answer.